# How to retrieve IAM Entities limits and current usage via Powershell

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-powershell

I need to retrieve the following current **count and capacity(limit)** for AWS account:

- users
- groups
- roles
- instance profiles
- server certificates per AWS account.

I have tried next commands:

- Get-EC2AccountAttributes,
- Describe methods of Ec2Client class

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As outlined in [Limitations on IAM Entities](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/LimitationsOnEntities.html), the [AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM)](http://aws.amazon.com/iam/) service limits can be retrieved by means of the [GetAccountSummary](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_GetAccountSummary.html) API.

The respective [AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell](http://aws.amazon.com/powershell/) cmdlet is [Get-IAMAccountSummary](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Get-IAMAccountSummary.html):

> Retrieves account level information about account entity usage and IAM quotas. [...]